# Using Dynamic SQL in User Defined Function to return string (not modify data)

Tags: dynamic-sql, user-defined-functions

Our document storage application has a unique database for each of our clients which are almost identical to each other, but one table `DocumentIndexes` is unique for each client and can have any number of columns and types.

I am trying to create a generic function (within our "master" database called `MYAPP_MASTER`) that I can call and simply pass in a database name and a document ID value and get back the column names and values from from the specified database's `DocumentIndexes` table. Because I have to pass in the database name, I have to generate the selection SQL dynamically and call `sp_executesql`.

I have the following code which polls the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` table to determine the columns needed and it works just fine in a stored procedure, but I hate having to copy all this code in every stored procedure that needs these to retrieve these dynamic column values. I would rather have one function that returns the string value of these columns regardless of database and have the function exist once in our `MYAPP_MASTER` database. Again, this code works, but SQL won't allow me to put it into a function.  Is there anyway around this?

```
USE MYAPP_MASTER
GO
DECLARE @DatabaseName varchar(255)
DECLARE @DocumentId int
SET @DatabaseName = 'SAMPLE_CLIENT_DB'
SET @DocumentId = 1234
DECLARE @DynamicIndexes nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @DynamicIndexesParam nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @DynamicIndexesSql nvarchar(max)
SET @DynamicIndexesParam = '@Indexes varchar(max) OUTPUT'
SET @DynamicIndexesSql = 'SELECT @Indexes = COALESCE(@Indexes + ''+ '''', '', '''') + CAST(COLUMN_NAME as varchar(max)) + '': '''''' + '' + CASE WHEN DI.'' + COLUMN_NAME + '' IS NOT NULL THEN CAST(DI.'' + COLUMN_NAME + '' as varchar(max)) ELSE '''''''' END '' FROM ' + @DatabaseName + '.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE table_name = ''DocumentIndexes'' AND COLUMN_NAME <> ''DocumentID''; '
EXEC sp_executesql @DynamicIndexesSql, @DynamicIndexesParam, @Indexes = @DynamicIndexes OUTPUT
SET @DynamicIndexes = '''' + @DynamicIndexes
DECLARE @SelectionSql nvarchar(max)
SET @SelectionSql = 'SELECT ' + @DynamicIndexes + ' as DocumentIndexes FROM ' + @DatabaseName + '..Document D LEFT OUTER JOIN ' + @DatabaseName + '..DocumentIndexes DI ON D.DocumentId = DI.DocumentId WHERE D.DocumentID = ' + CAST(@DocumentId as varchar(10))
EXEC sp_executesql @SelectionSql
```

If the `SAMPLE_CLIENT_DB` datababase `DocumentIndexes` table has columns for Name, Office and Classification, this code will return a simple string that looks like the following:

```
Name: Foo, Office: Bar, Classification: 123
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't run an Exec command inside a SQL function, but you could use a stored procedure with an output variable assuming the DocumentIndexes table is unique at the DocumentID level.

```
Create Proc DocID_DocIndexes @retval Varchar(Max) Output
As
...
(Your code logic minus last two lines)
...
--  Populate your dynamic SQL into a variable to assign it to the output variable
SET @SelectionSql = 'SELECT @result = ' + @DynamicIndexes + ' as DocumentIndexes FROM ' + @DatabaseName + '..Document D LEFT OUTER JOIN ' + @DatabaseName + '..DocumentIndexes DI ON D.DocumentId = DI.DocumentId WHERE D.DocumentID = ' + CAST(@DocumentId as varchar(10))
EXEC sp_executesql @SelectionSql, N'@result Varchar(Max) Output', @result = @retval Output
Return
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, but the reason I want this in a function is to be able to reuse the function in another query.  For example, let's say I want to be able to do something like `SELECT *, udfGetIndexes(DocumentID) as Indexes FROM Document`.  I don't know how I would do that with a SP, do you?

Comment: The only thing that might possibly work (and hopefully someone else will jump in to refute if I'm wrong) would be to create a SQL CLR function and pass it the documentID and then have the CLR call the stored procedure to return the varchar and return the results back to the CLR function. Purely within SQL I believe what you're trying to do is not possible without some degree of code reuse.